# Error when I try to register user with the Identity Storage in MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I managed to move my Identity Storage to my own MySQL database but I get this error when I try to register new users:

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'Extent1.Discriminator' in where clause']
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +306
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) +67
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) +17
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +110
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +794
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +1564
MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +33
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +176
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext() +249

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext() +334
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.<ExecuteAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() +1515
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext() +862
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext() +632
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
System.Data.Entity.Internal.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +261
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<FirstOrDefaultAsync>d__25`1.MoveNext() +349
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +689
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateUserName>d__4.MoveNext() +594
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +266
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +568
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +483
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
App.Controllers.<Register>d__15.MoveNext() in ...\Controllers\AccountController.cs:155
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9744373
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155`
```

I used the next script to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `asproles` (
  `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `aspusers` (
  `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `PasswordHash` longtext,
  `SecurityStamp` longtext,
  `PhoneNumber` longtext,
  `PhoneNumberConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `TwoFactorEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `LockoutEndDateUtc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LockoutEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `AccessFailedCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `aspuserclaims` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ClaimType` longtext,
  `ClaimValue` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Claims` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `aspusers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `aspuserlogins` (
  `LoginProvider` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ProviderKey` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LoginProvider`,`ProviderKey`,`UserId`),
  KEY `ApplicationUser_Logins` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Logins` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `aspusers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `aspuserroles` (
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `RoleId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`,`RoleId`),
  KEY `IdentityRole_Users` (`RoleId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Roles` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `aspusers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `IdentityRole_Users` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `asproles` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ;
```

And this lines of code to move the Identity Storage to those tables:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {  
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("aspusers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("aspusers");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("asproles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("aspuserroles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("aspuserclaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("aspuserlogins");
    }
}
```

Where is the error or the Extent1 table to find the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because your `asproles` and `aspusers` tables lack the `Discriminator` column. Add `Discriminator nvarchar(128) null` to those tables and you should be fine. For further read about this column you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054254/what-is-a-discriminator-column-in-asp-net-migrations).